# Ajax Form Won't Post

Tags: php, ajax, forms

Could someone explain or show me why my Ajax form won't post?. I'm using smarty template engine.

The form

```
<form action="/ajax/update_details.php" method="post" id="detailsform">
    <input type="text" name="city" value="{$profile_user.city}" />
    <input type="text" name="profile_message" value="{$profile_user.profile_message}" />
    <textarea name="about_me" cols="53" rows="5" class="submit_form_textfield">{$profile_user.about_me}</textarea>
    <textarea name="hobbies" cols="53" rows="5" class="submit_form_textfield">{$profile_user.hobbies}</textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="user_details" />
    <input type="submit" class="submit_form_button" value="Update Details" />
    <a class="success" style="display: none; color: green; text-align: centera;">Your details have been updated</a>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#detailsform").submit(function() {                                       
    var url = "/ajax/update_details.php";                               
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("#detailsform").serialize(),
        success: function(data)
        {
        $(".success").show(1000);
        $(".success").fadeOut(5000);
        }
    });                                     
    return false;
});
</script>
{/literal}
```

And update_details.php

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once('../vars.php');
require_once('../includes/user.class.php');

$user = new User();

if (isset($action) && $action=='user_details' && isset($_SESSION['loggeduser_id'])){

    $city = preg_replace("/[^a-z]/i","",$_POST['city']);
    $profile_message = preg_replace("/[^a-z]/i","",$_POST['profile_message']);
    $about_me = ($_POST['about_me']);
    $hobbies = ($_POST['hobbies']);

    $user->update($_SESSION['loggeduser_id'],array("city" => $city,"profile_message" => $profile_message,"about_me" => $about_me,"hobbies" => $hobbies));   
}

?>
```

Please could someone help me out as i'm new to coding it would be mostly appreciated

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: have you add the jquery library ?

Comment: Add document ready handler. `$(function(){  $("#detailsform").submit(function() {....}); });`

Comment: @SureshKamrushi No i ain't getting errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not waiting for the page to load, unless your script is right before `</body>` you need to use `$(document).ready(function() {` or `$(function(){` or any other valid syntax. NB, it needs closing too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#detailsform").submit(function(){  
         // etc
      });
});
</script>
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: sorry :) +1 for you. deleted mine

Answer (score 0):

Add document ready handler.

```
$(function(){ 
     $("#detailsform").submit(function() {
         //your stuff here....
       }); 
 });
```

Ref: [Ajax Form Won't Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814786/ajax-form-wont-post/20814873#comment31210365_20814786)

Comment: @popnoodles, Sorry I can't get you!!